# Show and hide android keyboard with javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, android, css, html

I'm developing an app in HTML5 with a screen that has login form.

When user enter on this screen immediately the virtual keyboard opens (without even hit the text field) and if the user never hits back button the keyboard never hides. So keyboard is still on screen while user is navigating through other screens.

My will is to hide the keyboard when user taps on anywhere outside the text field  or taps the back button.

How can I achieve that with CSS or Javascript?

Comment: I tried recreating a similar situation to the one you have but I haven't been successful. Would you be able to share code snippets from the project? And one other question for now is: are you using cordova or phonegap for the project?

Comment: Its something similar to this http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/livetests/run?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io%2Fanon%2Ffull%2FZGoMYr If you open that link in mobile browser you will see how the text field pops up immediatly the keyboard, btw I'm using Intel XDK so it will be Cordova

Comment: The virtual keyboard on my android browser (chrome) actually does not show up for me there... I don't think I can help here :x

Comment: maybe when the app loads it focus on some input element, try to force set the focus on somenthing else